# Riemann Prime Counting Function correction/pairing terms by Mathematica

Tags: prime-numbers, mathematica, riemann-hypothesis

Riemann Prime Counting Function:

[image]

The second correction/paring terms:

[image: sum_(rho)li(x^rho)=sum_(I[rho]>0)[Li(x^rho)+Li(x^(1-rho))]]

I tried to use Mathematica function LogIntegral to plot this second correction/paring terms, for example, when I only include the first 2 non-trivial zeros, and plot with range x from 1 to 5:
[image]

`Plot[Sum[LogIntegral[x^ZetaZero[k]] + LogIntegral[x^(1 - ZetaZero[k])], {k, 1, 2}], {x, 1, 5}]`

However, I got very large value instead of small correction:

[image]

I can also use simplified equation provided by[ [ref 1]](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1970-24-112/S0025-5718-1970-0277489-3/S0025-5718-1970-0277489-3.pdf):

[image]

[image]

`Plot[Sum[Exp[ZetaZero[k]*Log[x]]/(ZetaZero[k]*Log[x]), {k, 1, 2}] + Sum[Exp[(1 -ZetaZero[k])*Log[x]]/((1 - ZetaZero[k])*Log[x]), {k, 1, 2}], {x, 1, 5}]`

Then I got the correct result:

[image]

Anyone knows what is wrong for the LogIntegral one?

Thank you!

[ref [1]: H. Riesel and G Gohl, "Some Calculations Related to Riemann's Prime Number Formula," Mathematics of Computation, 24(112), 1970 pp. 969–983.](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1970-24-112/S0025-5718-1970-0277489-3/S0025-5718-1970-0277489-3.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried asking on Mathematica.StackExchange?